# php-fpm refuses to start (missing path /usr/var)

Tags: php

In the default php-fpm.conf file that comes with OS X, it says "the default prefix is /usr/var". However, this path does not exist on OS X, so php-fpm refuses to start.

I was able to remedy the situation by setting the `error_log = syslog`, but what is the best way to handle this situation? Simply create the missing directory?

All these UNIX path conventions are a bit of a blur to me.

```
; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; in a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is /usr/var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log
;error_log = log/php-fpm.log
```

Comment: creating a system level directory is usually not the best practice. Sending it to syslog is a good idea so its apart of the machine's central logging.  If you want to specify a directory there's probably a way to set the prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error_log = /var/log/php-fpm.log

Answer (score 0):

Open the PHP-FPM configuration file for editing:

`open -e /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php-fpm.conf`

Underneath the line that says `;error_log = log/php-fpm.log`, **add this line:**

`/var/log/php-fpm.log`

Save and close the `php-fpm.conf` file.

Start PHP-FPM:

`php-fpm`